# SQL query with correlated subquery in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am fighting with a SQL.

The task is to write max(EMP.SAL) for each project (PROJ_EMP.PROJNO)

I have 3 tables.

Table PROJ which keep data about projects:

```
PROJ.PROJNO | PROJ.NAME  
------------+-------------
    1       | PROJECT1  
    2       | PROJECT2  
    3       | PROJECT3
```

Table EMP for employees data:

```
EMP.EMPNO | EMP.NAME | EMP.SALARY  
----------+----------+------------
   1000   | name1    | 4000  
   1001   | name2    | 2000  
   1002   | name3    | 3000  
   1003   | name4    | 6000  
   1004   | name5    | 1000
```

And Table PROJ_EMP for connecting these projects with employees:

```
PROJ_EMP.EMPNO | PROJ_EMP.PROJNO  
---------------+----------------
     1000      |       1  
     1001      |       1  
     1002      |       2  
     1003      |       2  
     1004      |       3
```

Such I mentioned at the beginning post: I am trying to write max(EMP.SAL)for each project using a correlated subquery in where clause so the desired result should be:

```
PROJ_EMP.PROJNO | EMP.EMPNO | EMP.SAL  
----------------+-----------+---------
       1        |    1000   | 4000  
       2        |    1003   | 6000  
       3        |    1004   | 1000
```

I don't have any working result however my SQL query closed to aim looks:

```
SELECT EMP.EMPNO, EMP.SAL, PROJ_EMP.PROJNO 
FROM EMP, PROJ_EMP   
WHERE EMP.EMPNO = PROJ_EMP.EMPNO 
  AND EMP.SAL = (SELECT MAX(EMP.SAL) 
                 FROM EMP, PROJ_EMP p_e 
                 WHERE EMP.EMPNO = PROJ_EMP.EMPNO 
                   AND PROJ_EMP.PROJNO = p_e.PROJNO)  
GROUP BY 
    PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.SAL, EMP.EMPNO  
ORDER BY 
    PROJ_EMP.PROJNO, EMP.SAL DESC
```

By the result are not like I expected. Can you help me? Thank you fo any help in advance

Comment: I would try some query redesign, but even with this query try to give alias to external PROJ_EMP and explicitly specify it in internal WHERE clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  I think you are trying to write:

```
SELECT e.EMPNO, e.SAL, pe.PROJNO
FROM EMP e JOIN
     PROJ_EMP pe 
     ON e.EMPNO = pe.EMPNO   
WHERE EMP.SAL = (SELECT MAX(EMP.SAL) 
                 FROM EMP e2 JOIN
                      PROJ_EMP pe2
                      ON e2.EMPNO = pe2.EMPNO 
                 WHERE pe2.PROJNO = pe.PROJNO   
                )
ORDER BY pe.PROJNO, e.SAL DESC ;
```

Comment: Thank you. I completely lost myself and forgot about JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `inner join` among three tables and filter by `max` analytic function partitioned by project number and ordered by descending salary to determine the max salaries for each project number :

```
select projno, empno, salary 
  from
  (
   select p.projno, e.empno, e.salary, 
          max(e.salary) over (partition by p.projno order by e.salary desc) as max_salary
     from proj p
     join proj_emp pe on pe.projno = p.projno
     join emp e on e.empno = pe.empno
   )
  where salary = max_salary;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c523a8fa28ae4cf91bc13f452a789433)</kbd>